# Everything is correct but htaccess redirects?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I know this has been asked before but Ive not found one solution. I have the same source on same server but under another domain works fine. But for some reason on this domain:

I get too many redirects

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ropanel.pw/$1 [R,L]
```

if i go to https:// manually on my site without a .htaccess it works fine? I cant even to get it to work even if I use php to force the https://

Comment: Not sure I see the problem when I access `http://ropanel.pw/`. The page is loading fine.

Comment: Thats because I removed the .htaccess.

Comment: So this is what web server, apache? THe normative docs at apache.org then add hints like "[...] SERVER_PORT depend[s] on the value[...] of [...] UseCanonicalPhysicalPort [...]". Next I would tend to not allow empty strings but instead of `^(.*)$` have `^(.+)$` in the rule. Otherwise I'ld suggest to check if something else obvious redirects back from https to http port.

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your rewrite rule to this.

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

I don't think what you have is right.